# Error while Installing PostgreSQL to Xammp

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I'm installing postgreSQL by this guide: http://w3guy.com/integrate-postgresql-database-xampp-windows/

My system: win8.1 x64, XAMPP 3.2.2, PHP 5.2.0, apache 2.4;
Apache stopped to launch after adding lines:

```
LoadFile “C:\xampp\php\libpq.dll”
```

into httpd.conf  and

```
Alias /phppgadmin “C:/xampp/phppgadmin/”
<Directory “C:/xampp/phppgadmin”>
AllowOverride AuthConfig
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

into httpd-xampp.conf:
( this "(*)" added for showing this only here, no "(*)" in configs)

Errors in apache:

> AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an
>   ID which matches the server name

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error you've listed doesn't refer to the changes you've made.  I'd query if the code you added is identical to what you actually added. `“` and `”` are not the same as `"`

Comment: This might be useful http://serverfault.com/questions/578061/rsa-certificate-configured-for-server-does-not-include-an-id-which-matches-the-s

Comment: oh... Yes, you`re right, i'm just blind dumbass-_- Just copied from guide-_-

Comment: Thanks, but i don't know how to  make your comment to answer

Answer (score 0):

The error you've listed doesn't refer to the changes you've made. I'd query if the code you added is identical to what you actually added. `“` and `”` are not the same as `"`

This might be useful https://serverfault.com/questions/578061/rsa-certificate-configured-for-server-does-not-include-an-id-which-matches-the-s